# Can't install phantomjs on server

Tags: phantomjs

I'm having a difficult time getting phantomjs installed on my server. I haven't found very good directions anywhere and the best I've found give me errors when I try to complete them. As of now I'm following these steps and getting these errors.

Successfully used putty to login as root and run the following commands

```
Line 1: yum install fontconfig freetype freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libstdc++
No errors


Line 2: wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
No errors

Line 3: mkdir -p /opt/phantomjs
No errors

Line 4: tar -xjvf ~/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 --strip-components 1 /opt/phantomjs/
Error: opt/phantomjs: Not found in archive
```

For this error (line 4) I ftp into my server and didn't see any directory for opt/phantomjs. I created one but am having the same "Not found in archive" error.

After this the only other lines of code, from what I've found, should be:

```
Line 5: ln -s /opt/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
Line 6: phantomjs /opt/phantomjs/examples/hello.js
```

If anyone has any insight I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well after a lot of trial and error it seems to be working (so far). The problem was the syntax of line 4. This solved the issue and line 5 and 6 worked fine.

```
UPDATED LINE 4: tar -xjvf ~/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 --strip-components=1 -C /opt/phantomjs/
```

Hopefully this helps someone else having the same issue.

Anyone know of a good tutorial on using it for highcharts in php?

Comment: Thanks alot! I had the same issue on Centos 6.6

Comment: Work for me. I follow this [tutorial](https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Install_PhantomJS_on_CentOS)to install, but can't work because the lack of `-C`

Answer (score 0):

I used this command to place the binay in /usr/local/bin

```
curl -Ls https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v1.9.19/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 | tar jxvf - --strip-components=2 -C /usr/local/bin/ ./phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```